# Using variables within a dynamic sql script

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm currently editing a procedure, let's call it `A`, that does some manipulations of a temporary table created in procedure `B` (so procedure B calls A). Procedure B contains one argument, which is the name of the said temporary table.

That being said, we need to retrieve all the columns (in a CSV) of the temporary table into a variable. Since the name is not the same everytime, I need to use dynamic SQL.

Here is what I have:

```
-- Input parameters: @sTempTableName VARCHAR(MAX) --> Name of the temporary table to alter

DECLARE 
    @sColumns               AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sAlterTableDynamicSQL  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

            
SET @sAlterTableDynamicSQL =
'
    SELECT @sColumns = @sColumns + [name] + N'','' FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns WHERE [object_id] = object_id(''tempdb..' + @sTempTableName + ''')
'

PRINT (@sAlterTableDynamicSQL)
EXEC (@sAlterTableDynamicSQL)
```

This fails saying that I need to declare `@sColumns` since it does not exists (I guess variables aren't shared between connections). How can I manage to do this ? I figured I could create another temporary table to hold that CSV, but I'm thinking there should be another way.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using and what are you expecting ```@sAlterTableDynamicSQL``` to be after it is set?

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL, you can pass a variable to `object_id`? Your dynamic SQL doesn't seem to make sense, is there something missing?

Comment: If you use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which is the best practice way to execute dynamic SQL), you can pass parameters in and out.

Comment: @Otter `@sAlterTableDynamicSQL` is expected to be  `SELECT @sColumns = @sColumns + [name] + N',' FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns WHERE [object_id] = object_id('tempdb..#tempTable')`, if the name of the table is `#tempTable`. `@sColumns` should be the list of the columns, separated by commas (for example, if there are 2 columns, ID and Name, we should have: `ID,Name,`. MySQL version is `SQL Server 2016`

Comment: @Charlieface I need it in order to pass the name of the table that comes from the input of the procedure. I added comments to make it more clear

Comment: @DaleK I'll check it out, was not aware of that

Comment: I still don't get why you need dynamic SQL, you can pass the table name straight through from the variable as I show below `object_id('temdb..' + QUOTENAME(@sTempTableName))`.

Comment: I was not aware of `QUOTENAME` to pass names, I always thought I needed dynamic SQL

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is just used to put brackets `[]` in where necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can pass through variables to dynamic SQL via `sp_executesql`**

- Note that you should always use `QUOTENAME` to escape object names
- Also, dynamic SQL variables should always be `nvarchar`
- You also should not use variable coalescing to aggregate, instead use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML`

```sql
DECLARE 
    @sColumns               AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sAlterTableDynamicSQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sGUID                  AS VARCHAR(MAX) = CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(MAX))

            
SET @sAlterTableDynamicSQL =
'
SELECT @sColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST([name] AS nvarchar(max)), N'','')
FROM Tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = object_id(N''tempdb..' + QUOTENAME(@sNomTableTemporaire, '''') + ''');
';

PRINT (@sAlterTableDynamicSQL);

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sAlterTableDynamicSQL,
  N'@sColumns nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'
  @sColumns = @sColumns OUTPUT;
```

**But you don't actually need dynamic SQL here at all.** You can pass the table name straight to `object_id()`

```
DECLARE 
    @sColumns               AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sAlterTableDynamicSQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sGUID                  AS VARCHAR(MAX) = CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            
SELECT @sColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST([name] AS nvarchar(max)), N',')
FROM Tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = object_id(N'tempdb..' + QUOTENAME(@sNomTableTemporaire));
```

> For SQL Server 2016 and earlier, you can use the `FOR XML PATH('')` method

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it avoids using dynamic SQL. NOte to others, `STRING_AGG` is available only in 2017+ SQL Server version

Answer (score 2):

You should use sp_executesql statement. It would look like this:

```
DECLARE 
    @sColumns                NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sAlterTableDynamicSQL   NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @temptableid INT = 3;
        
SELECT @sAlterTableDynamicSQL =
    N'SELECT @sColumns = STRING_AGG([name], '','') FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns WHERE [object_id] =  + CAST(@temptableid AS VARCHAR(10))';

EXEC sp_executesql @sAlterTableDynamicSQL, N'@sColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT, @temptableid INT', @sColumns = @sColumns OUTPUT, @temptableid = @temptableid

SELECT @sColumns;
```